# Is it unsafe to switch environments based on domain?

Tags: php, security, environment

I am curious if doing something like setting your "environment" to Production, Dev, Staging, etc. based on a domain name such as dev.domain.com, staging.domain.com is a bad idea.

Can somebody just edit their hosts file to point dev.domain.com to domain.com so now the system *thinks* it's in Dev when it really is in Prod? This would mean any Dev specific code will be ran by a complete stranger.

Is this possible or is there a better way to determine your environment such as setting it manually in a server variable?

For reference, I am using PHP.

Comment: It really depends on how you have set up your subdomains, and the way your system detects what mode it is in. What people often do is password protect the dev. and staging. domains

Comment: @Pekka I am asking about using this method to detect which mode I am in. Protecting the DEV and STAGING with passwords would work if you had to log in to the system to view anything, but if you had something like `htpasswd` on the DEV site but they are really getting served the PROD version (because they rerouted via hosts) then they wouldn't even get the password box, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the environment in a server variable on the machine.  This allows you to control it during deployment and it cannot be mucked around with by people who are not authorized to do so.  Although if you are worried about developers inadvertently connecting to production that is a whole other issue.  You should be controlling access to production credentials via some other process such as jndi (in the java world) or environment keys replaced at runtime or deploy time (works in any language).

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far. Thanks gwhitake!

Answer (score 0):

Setting your "environment" to Production, Dev, Staging, etc. based on a domain name is absolutely safe. This is, because you have total control about what your domain name is.

BEWARE: do not trust what others make you believe what your domain name is. For example, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not your domain name. It is the value of the HTTP Host header, that the client sent you, and is therefore free to manipulate.

Comment: Setting it based on the domain name isn't safe.  A simple change to the hosts file or local DNS server can easily point dev.domain.com to a non-dev site.

Comment: Which hosts file are you talking about? And why would you want to use an untrusted DNS server?

Comment: The hosts file on the computer of the person trying to access the dev environment by spoofing the hostname.  DNS would just be an alternative to editing the hosts file by setting up static DNS for their dev domain to return the live IP to allow the hostname to resolve.

Comment: @Oswald, your answer is a bit confusing since first you say it is absolutely safe then you say don't trust it. So if it is safe, how would you check it without using the `HTTP_HOST`?

Answer (score 0):

This is depends on how do you use your domain? Suppose that there are domain.com but there are  several sub-domain, sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc and every sub domain is managed by different user and/or application!